# Get all class name icon from fontawesome

Tags: c#

I'd like to get all class name icon from fontawesome to list or array in c# from fontawesome.
I'd like to get all variants icon for example:

```
fas fa-abacus
far fa-abacus
fal fa-abacus
...
```

I tried to extract it from the css file, but it only gets the icon names themselves without prefixes.

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(@"fontawesome\all.css");
var allMatches = Regex.Matches(text, @"^\.fa\-(.*):", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Thank's for help.
Monika

Answer (score 2):

```
public List<string> ListOfFontAwesomeIcons(string FilePath)
{
   List<string> response = new List<string>();
   List<string> fontAwesomePrefixes = new {  "fas", "far" /*manually add all prefixes*/ }
   var textLines = File.ReadAllLines($"{FilePath}");
   foreach(string l in textLines)
   {
       foreach(string p in fontAwesomePrefixes)
       {
          if(l.Contains(p))
            response.Add(l.Replace($"{p} "));    
       }
   }

   return response;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it not works, because file all.css not include information about available prefix for the icon.

Comment: @monika-115 show mi this file, i understood that its in your example

Comment: You will need to add the prefix information manually into the variable fontAwesomePrefixes. You should be able to determine them by quickly reviewing the css file or FontAwesome's documentation. They don't have many prefixes.

Comment: The problem is that the fontawesome some icon not have all prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this in C# 9, VS2019 just based off of feeding it a test string, and it worked for me. I double-checked for `fa-` in the result list to make sure I excluded all of the other results.

Also, I just converted to List of strings for display. You don't really need to do that, depending on what you're doing with your results.

EDIT: Code updated to reflect FA's .css file available on their website, not the format of the string I was using earlier.

Replace the path in the first line with whatever reflects your project. Note that there are faster methods than ReadAllText, but it should be fine for this.

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("./wwwroot/css/all.css");

var allMatches = Regex.Matches(text, "(?<=[.]).*?(fa-)?.*?(?=[:])", RegexOptions.None);
List<string> allMatchesStrings = new();

foreach (var item in allMatches)
{
    if (item.ToString().Contains("fa-"))
        allMatchesStrings.Add(item.ToString());
}

foreach (var item in allMatchesStrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Ok, Ok in the case of such a string everything works.
The problem is that fontawesome does not provide anything like the string you wrote anywhere.

Comment: You can just read the css file as a string or manipulate/read it as necessary. The main thing I wanted to show was the regex expression and `.Contains("fa-"))` logic. I will update my answer to include the file read portion of the code later when I have more time.

Comment: Try the updated code. Should match the all.css on FA's website. Please upvote/mark as correct if it solves your problem.